# Integrate forum with chat in yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I want to implement forum with chat, My application is built in yii2.

So now I am using PhpBB forum and installed it with following reference :
https://github.com/8sun/yii2-integration-phpBB3.1

but as mention in readme file

> Part 3: Change forum settings
>
> Change method get_container_filename() in \forum\phpbb\di\container_builder.php

**but there is no such file exist in installable directory.**

So please can anyone help me with the same.

Or is is there any better replacement of phpbb then thats most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : You have to download the PHPwb latest zip from the link :

https://www.phpbb.com/files/release/phpBB-3.1.8.zip.

Step 2 : Then you have to add new folder named "forum" in your root directory and paste all the above unziped files to this "forum" folder.

You will get \forum\phpbb\di\container_builder.php.

Hope this will help you :)